# Ethernet port plastic plug blocking port access on server

Tags: ethernet, physical-environment

I have Dell Poweredge server with plastic blockers inside their ethernet ports. My problem is that I don't know how to take it out. You can see photo of the plug here:

[image: ethernet plastic plug]

I tried to pull them out, or to squeeze and then pull, but they don't move. I cannot find anything on the Dell installation manual, so it's probably not provided by Dell.

Did you see this kind of plugs and do you know how to take them out without risking to break something?

Comment: Looks sort of like an [RJ45 blockout device](http://www.cableorganizer.com/panduit/rj45-jack-blockout-device/). I've not seen them ship on Dell equipment though.

Comment: Sounds like what jscott is saying may be the case, but I wonder if that's because gb3 and gb4 are shared with a DRAC or some other "upgrade/add-on" that wasn't included with the purchase?  Have you contacted Dell to ask them?  If it is a blockout you can follow this if you dare: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7cKxLUCw7Q

Comment: Interesting, I did not contact Dell yet, since I did not receive device from Dell directly. It looks different than Panduit but it could be only a different manufacturer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are PadJack Locks.:

[image]
<sub>(source: [padjack.com](http://www.padjack.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/padjack_sv_sm1.png))</sub>

They can't be removed without breaking them. They don't come from Dell that way, someone else installed them. They're meant to be difficult to removed, and tamper-evident.

If I remember correctly the back end has a "top" and "bottom" that you pry up/down (apart) until it snaps. I could be wrong, it's been a while since I've seen them, so don't quote me on that...

Comment: Yes looking at their web site, it's definately this device. So now I need to check why did they put them there (server was part of the other system 2 years ago). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I have removed one of these using a drill and a few drill bits. Use around a 1/8" bit to drill a pilot hole, then a 1/4" to make it larger, then maybe a 5/16". Once it's large enough, you can just pry out the pieces with some needle-nose pliers. It's not for the faint of heart, but it did work. If I had to do it again, I'd probably try the paperclip method mentioned in the comments first.

Comment: Thanks ben. So you had the same device? It really is blockout device? I was thinking that I am simply not trying to take it out the right way.

Comment: Yes, they're put there for security purposes (PCI/HIPAA) usually. I picked up a few servers a while back from a small business which was closing, and one of them had this installed in it. I needed them to work quickly, so I just went the brute force tactic.